# Why doesn't it work correctly to write in the file?

Tags: java

I am currently trying to program a small API, but with my writeToFile method, even if I use true in the method, it deletes everything that is in the file and only writes in the text of the user (@param text).

What did I do wrong ? I tried to print the string, but it appears to be empty. If I only use the readFile method of mine, it reads out the whole file correctly.

Need help.

```
package at.tornaduuu.usefullapi.files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileUtils {
    public static void writeToFile(String text, File file, boolean keepIndexText) {
        try {
            String indexText = "";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            if (keepIndexText) {
                indexText = FileUtils.readFile(file);
                System.out.println(indexText);
                FileUtils.clearFile(file);
                fw.write(indexText + text);
                fw.close();
            }
            else {
                fw.write(text);
                fw.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void clearFile(File file) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            fw.write("");
            fw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String readFile(File file) {
        String fileIndex = "";
        int unicode;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            try {
                while ((unicode = fr.read()) != -1) {
                    fileIndex += (char) unicode;
                }
                fr.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: log what you have in `indexText` and see if it contains the file text

Comment: Why can't you open the file in append mode instead of first reading the file and then writing to it?

Comment: I recommend the following tutorial: [File I/O (Featuring NIO.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not appending to file, you are just rewriting it. That's because FileWriter is not set to append. You can change this:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file); //rewrites file every time write() method is called
```

to:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true); //append text in file when write() is called
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [`FileWriter(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File)) which in turn will call [`FileOutputStream(String name, append = False)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean)). So your file is getting truncated before you read content.

There is another constructor [`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean)) that you can use with `keepIndexText`, in such case your `FileUtils.clearFile(file);` is pretty useless.